# g++ macro concatenation vs c++ macro concatenation

Tags: c++, linux, string, macros, g++

I'm porting a windows based c++ project into windows, and I ran into the following error.

```
UeiDaqAnsiC.cpp:105:24
error: expected ')' before string constant
UEI_ERROR(__FUNCTION__ " error: %s\n", e.getErrorMessage());
```

It looks as though linux is unable to concatenate the `__FUNCTION__` macro with the following string. This is confusing, as the project compiles and builds just fine in Windows.

As a quick fix, it appears simply adding a `,` between the `__FUNCTION__` and `"error: %s\n", e.getErrorMessage()` completely fixes it.

The new fixed line looks like this `UEI_ERROR(__FUNCTION__, " error: %s\n", e.getErrorMessage());`

I came here because im not well versed on the linux g++ compiler, and I want to know if this is a valid workaround for this error, before I fix all 130 lines where this error occurs.

EDIT: I also want to ask if the comma keeps the functionality of simply concatenating the macro and string

EDIT2: `UEI_ERROR` is defined as 
`#define UEI_ERROR(...) UeiPalTraceOutputWithLevel(UeiPalTraceError, __VA_ARGS__)`

Comment: @Scheff my apologies, added the definition in the edit.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124994/why-cant-a-string-literal-be-concatenated-to-function

Comment: With the link of @NathanOliver in mind, you could pass the `__FUNCTION__` as another arg. for the format string: `UEI_ERROR("%s error: %s\n", __FUNCTION__, e.getErrorMessage());`

Comment: @NathanOliver I dont believe its a dupe because im asking first why does the error get thrown on linux and not on windows, and Im also asking if the fix I stated above will change the functionality of the line of code, or simply fix the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__FUNCTION__` is not a string literal and cannot be concatenated by preprocessor with other string literal.

Your "fix" by adding `,` changes the meaning, mostly as

```
printf(__FUNCTION__ " format %i", 42);        // MyFunction format 42
printf("MyFunction", "unused format %i", 42); // MyFunction
```

Real fix would be to change the format and reorder parameter:

```
UEI_ERROR("%s error: %s\n", __FUNCTION__, e.getErrorMessage());// MyFunction error: error message.
```